# DateEdit.DateTime Property - Gets or sets the date/time value edited within the control

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datetime, devexpress

A System.DateTime object representing selected date/time value. How can i change that?

If i set dateEdit as:

```
            dateEdit1.DateTime = New DateTime(2015, 12, 31)

            dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = True
            dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = Mask.MaskType.DateTimeAdvancingCaret
            dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.AutoComplete = Mask.AutoCompleteType.None
            dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "dd.MM.yy"
```

when control get focus my date just as I expected is:

```
             dateEdit1.DateTime = 31.12.15
```

My problem starts when i start to change the value, then my control value is reversed to system.datetime and i get the Current date

```
             dateEdit1.DateTime = 16.03.16
```

DateTime returns the value of the BaseEdit.EditValue property converted to System.DateTime.

```
My only solution is to change System.DateTime to: 31.12.15
```

Is there other way?

Comment: can you be more specific? Do you want to default the control to 31.12.15? In case when you select some date, it should display that date and when you haven't, it should display 31.12.15?

Comment: yes the default should be 31.12.15. When users start to modifed value then control always looks for System.DateTime and reversed into current date.

Comment: i think you can just have an if condition to check if it is your default value "31.12.15", if not, let the system take the value selected by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dateEdit1.DateTime = New DateTime(2015, 12, 31)
dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = True
dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = Mask.MaskType.Custom
dateEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "dd.MM.yy"
```